# Is there a database of emission spectra of wavenumber and intensity for all elements?

Tags: resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, elements

Is there a database of emission spectra of wavenumber and intensity for all elements?

I have been trying to get the emission spectra of all elements from the [Atomic Spectra Database](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database) but from what I can tell there is no easy way to get all of the data. Please, I just need a simple spreadsheet of the emission spectrum in the format of wavenumber and intensity for all of the elements.

Once I have that, then I can start interpreting the data from my spectrometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't anything more comprehensive than the [NIST ASD](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database), which you've already found.

- If what you want is to do a direct data import into some other program, then you can choose to get the output as ASCII and re-import or re-process that in your software of choice.
- If you want to get a comprehensive list that's not narrowed by element, then you can do an `All Spectra` search by leaving the element field blank and specifying a wavelength range.

(For more on the different ways you can interact with the data, see the NIST ASD help pages.) I would be *extremely* surprised is there is anything like what you're looking for that's not listed in the [ASD's Other Databases page](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-databases).

And also, just to be clear: the line intensity is not something that can make it into databases, because it depends on the conditions of the emission, including temperature and pressure. (As a basic example, increasing the temperature will increase the strength of the higher components of any Rydberg series because there's more population in those states to transition from; you get [even more changes with molecules](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200619/temperature-dependence-of-spectra). Similarly, if you're doing absorption spectra, then you need the lower state to be populated, and that population decreases with temperature.)

What you *can* (and do) get in databases are measures of the transition strength, such as the oscillator strength or the Einstein A coefficient, and those give an indication of how strong the line will be, but they are never a direct predictor of the intensities you will observe in any particular experiment.